# scala - modeling methods as classes

Tags: scala

I want to create a kind of components about `moving` geometrical units in some games. So, I am trying in this way:

```
trait Move 
case class MoveHorizontal(val velocityMvH: Int) extends Move
case class MoveVertical(val velocityMvV: Int) extends Move
case class MoveRandomly() extends Move
case class MoveDiagonally(val velocityMvDx: Int = 0, val velocityMvDy: Int = 0) extends Move
case class MoveDiagonal() extends Move
case class MoveReverseX() extends Move
case class MoveReverseY() extends Move

class Moving(gu: GeometricalUnit, mv: () => Unit) extends Move {
  val velocity = 20
  var xVelocity: Int = velocity
  var yVelocity: Int = -velocity

  if (gu.isMovable == true) {    
    mv match {
      case MoveHorizontal(mvH) => gu.dim.x += mvH
      case MoveVertical(mvV) => gu.dim.y += mvV
      case MoveRandomly() => moveRandomly()
      case MoveDiagonally(mvDx, mvDy) =>  moveDiagonally(mvDx, mvDy)
      case MoveDiagonal() => moveDiagonally()
      case MoveReverseX() => xVelocity *= -1
      case MoveReverseY() => yVelocity *= -1        
    }
  }  
}
```

thus, I want to call later as `properties` let say of these GeometricalUnits in order to make them moving according special functions...
I would like to know if a better organization can be than mine which seems boring?!

---

My solution:
this is my solution in general:

```
def initiatePieces(s: Movable, x: Int, y: Int) = {
nrInitiations += 1
s.dimM.x = x
s.dimM.y = y
s match {
  case _: BBall => randomMvmBB()
  case _: WBall => randomMvmWB()
  case _: PBall => randomMvmPB()
  case _ => "nothing"
}
```

}

this is how I am initiating pieces, in the same way I am moving them with another method that is calling functions based on the Movable Pieces Types

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but those cases seem pretty redundant.

Comment: `Move` trait should be sealed either way

Comment: how about starting with `case class Direction(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int)`

Comment: what I am trying to do is: I have different `move` methods for each geometricalUnit and I am trying now to find a way how I can create only a single method or class and to use it in every case?!

Answer (score 1):

How about this ?

```
def Move(what:Movable, where:MoveFunction) : Movable
```

should take a `Movable` (an immutable state object of what you want to move) and a higher-order function `MoveFunction` where you want to move it (a function that can be applied to a `Movable`. Each function should then take an existing state and return a new state by applying the higher order function (`MoveFunction`)  to the `Movable` object.

Comment: Please post your solution. Would be nice to see what solution you used.

Comment: At the end of my question, up, is my reply. Probably it's not the best in the world...:)